# What should a well behaved drupal module delete on uninstall?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm creating a drupal module and I would like to ask what I should actually delete as part of the uninstall process. My module creates a new node type, so does it mean that I should also actually delete all data of that node type? What would users expect the behavior to be and how can I make update of the module as smooth as possible for users?

Thanks!

Comment: I would say, all the things your module created should be removed on module un-install.

Comment: That's a bit inconclusive. What about the stuff the user created with the help of the module? I.e. content for nodes where the module has created the node types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything the module created, including module specific variables, database tables, content types that only it can handle, views specific to those types, etc.

Comment: Ok! If there is user created content of a content type created by the module, should the content be deleted too?

Comment: Can you confirm that also the content, i.e. the actual nodes, that has the node type where the node type is created by the module, should also be deleted? I'll accept the answer if you can make this clarification...

Comment: That depends on if the content type can be handled without the custom module. The answer is almost always yes, the content needs to go to.